# Horizontally scroll Angular Material Stepper form header items

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-8

I have an Angular Material Stepper form and I have 15 steps on it. As there are a lot of steps, the header text is shrinking down and the text cannot be seen. Please refer to the image  below:

[image]

I am trying to set a fixed width to each header item and as well as make the header horizontally scrollable like it does in Material Tabs. The code I have used is below:

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r8m1h8?)

Please help me get this done.

Comment: can you please create a project in stackbliz

Comment: @Dakopatel here you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r8m1h8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important `Add CSS in style.css`
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swzbpn

```
.mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
  width: fit-content !important;
}
```